# Set of Foreign Keys Where All But One Are NULL

Tags: database, database-design, orm, polymorphic-associations

What is the name for the technique of using a set of foreign keys in a table where all but one are NULL for a given row?

In other words, each row needs a foreign key to one (and only one) of n different possible tables so you actually have all the necessary foreign keys but all but one are NULL.

(users of Django may recognize this as an alternative to using a Generic Foreign Key)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term for the design you're describing is **Exclusive Arc**.

Instead, I prefer to make one foreign key that references a common super-table of your n different parent tables.

See my other answers for polymorphic associations:

- [Possible to do a MySQL foreign key to one of two possible tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441001/possible-to-do-a-mysql-foreign-key-to-one-of-two-possible-tables/441111#441111)
- [Referencing foreign keys in the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759008/referencing-foreign-keys-in-the-same-column/759100#759100)
- [Why can you not have a foreign key in a polymorphic association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922184/why-can-you-not-have-a-foreign-key-in-a-polymorphic-association/922341#922341)
- [In a StackOverflow clone, what relationship should a Comments table have to Questions and Answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987654/in-a-stackoverflow-clone-what-relationship-should-a-comments-table-have-to-quest/987709#987709)
- [How to handle an “OR” relationship in an ERD (table) design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098429/how-to-handle-an-or-relationship-in-an-erd-table-design/2098477#2098477)

Answer (score 2):

It would have been easier with a example, but a common way to untangle this is simply to find a common super-type for those tables. Suppose that we have tables `Book, Article, Magazine` and now a table has to have foreign key to these tables. Using a common super-type `Publication`resolves this. **[See here for the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654071/db-design-to-use-sub-type-or-not/1654483#1654483)** and the similar question/answer.