# Database: How do I relate an ID to EVERY table? (many to many to many!)

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I'm designing a relational database, and I would like to know best practice for the following problem:

I have a table called "links", which contains URLs.

Most of my other tables relate to objects which appear throughout my
   site, such as "news", "music", "banners" - and these are joined with
   one-to-many or many-to-many relationships in the usual way. So far so
   good...

The links table (link_id) can apply to almost ANY of my objects. For
   example, "news" could have many "link_id, one "link_id" could apply
   to many "music". Many "banners" could share many "link_id" - links
   are important to my site!

I can think of two solutions for this :

1) create a junction table for each new object to which "link_id" applies, thus creating dozens of new tables, and adding new ones each time I add an new object to my application.

```
>##*Table: links_to_news*##

>##*Table: links_to_music*##

>##*Table: links_to_banners*##

> etc... etc... etc...
```

2) reference the table name in a single new table, and create a join, ie:

```
>##Table: links##

>| link_id | link_url |

>##*Table: links_to_tables* ##
>*| link_id | a_table_name | id_within_that_table |*

> ##Table: news##

>| news_id | news_text | 

> ##Table : music ##

>| music_id | music_text |
```

Both of these methods seem a little bit clunky to me. So is there a correct way to do what I need? Thanks.

Comment: Search for "polymorphic associations". FYI there is a third solution, creating a "linkeable" table, with nothing but a unique ID. Your tables "news", "music", etc. will all have a unique "linkeable_id". Then you create a junction table `(linkeable_id, link_id)`. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922184/why-can-you-not-have-a-foreign-key-in-a-polymorphic-association/922341#922341

Comment: are objects 'news', 'music', 'banners' etc contained in single table? Or you have different tables for each object?

Comment: ^different tables for each

Comment: re. the "linkable_id" option - each entry could have many of these... I'm not sure if thats the correct way...

Comment: How about bit customized version of your proposed solution 2: Make new table for links ( linkid | url ) and then use it's primary key as Foreign key in all the news, banners, music tables?

Comment: @Leon No, each entry (news, music, etc.) only has one "linkable_id". But each "linkable" object can have many link_id in the junction table.

Comment: OK, so it would appear to be a polymorphic association, thanks for making me aware of that. I see what you are saying! Each "linkable" object is an entity in its own right. Yes, I think that will work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to implement a polymorphic relation/assocation. First option is difficult to maintain/extend. Second option is more flexible, but doesn't allow foreign keys, which might not be desirable.

In this case there is a third solution you need to consider. You will need a "supertable" storing one global unique ID for all objects that can have links. The table could be called `linkables` for example. It only has one column (a unique auto increment ID). Each table (news, music, etc.) has a `linkable_id` column, which is a foreign key. In OOP terms, you're making your News, Music (...) classes inherit from an (abstract) Linkable class. Then you create a junction table `(linkable_id, link_id)`.

Basically, you are moving the "link" relationship to a "parent" table, thereby removing the polymorphism.

Suggested reads:

- [Foreign key to one of many tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383300/foreign-key-to-one-of-many-tables)
- [Why can you not have a foreign key in a polymorphic association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922184/why-can-you-not-have-a-foreign-key-in-a-polymorphic-association/922341#922341)