# Database foreign key from multiplier tables

Tags: mysql, database

I've facing a trouble, and i need your help please:

If we assume is that there is a table called **page** has and **id**, **name**, and **creation_date**.

Also if there's another table called **user** has and **id**, **name**, **birthdate**.

Also if there's another table called **admin** has and **id**, **name**, **is_super_admin**

The last table is **post** has **writer** and **content**.

The problem is that: **the post write can be an page or an user or an admin. So how can i set the post.writer column as foreign key from all of (*page.id*, *user.id* and *admin.id*).** How can the database define is that for example [writer = "1"] refers for a an page, admin or an user?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383300/foreign-key-to-one-of-many-tables

Answer (score 0):

Your common elements are id and name between page, user and admin.  The "is_super_admin" is a property of an admin level user, and the property "birthdate" belongs to "users", and "creation_date" belongs to pages.  One can make the argument that "birthdate" and "creation_date" are synonymous.  Assemble your common elements into a single entities table and use additional child tables to hold the unique properties.  Define your table schema based on the data, not the real world objects being represented.